# Problems on AWS Firehose intermediate S3 bucket and delivery stream dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

1. Is is a good idea to set one s3 bucket for multiple delivery streams? (ex: consider two delivery streams having different streaming throughput, s3 buffer size / buffer interval...)
2. If two delivery streams (S1, S2) are routing data into redshift. S1 is delivering data into T1, and S2 to T2. In T2 there's a foreign key constraint on T1. Is it possible to guarantee that when S2 delivers data (D2) to T2, all records in T1 referenced by D2 have already been delivered by S1 ? (i.e. there are dependencies in delivery streams)

BTW I'm using firehose to push my application log into redshift for analytics.

Answer (score 1):

1. S3 buckets are designed to store practically infinite data, so answer to your question is, definitely yes.
2. Even though you can define foreign keys, Redshift doesn't actually enforces them *at all*. From the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html),

> Uniqueness, primary key, and foreign key constraints are informational
>   only; *they are not enforced by Amazon Redshift*. Nonetheless, primary
>   keys and foreign keys are used as planning hints and they should be
>   declared if your ETL process or some other process in your application
>   enforces their integrity.

Answer (score 0):

*Assumptions: T1 and T2 are tables in the same Redshift cluster.*

You can (virtually) have as many S3 buckets as you want. It's not a good idea to use the same S3 bucket for two delivery streams, as the COPY command performed by Redshift to load the data into the cluster will look into the same Manifest folder, for both delivery streams.

From Amazon Kinesis Firehose FAQ:

> Q: What is the manifests folder in my Amazon S3 bucket?
>
> For Amazon Redshift destination, Amazon Kinesis Firehose generates manifest files to load Amazon S3 objects to Redshift cluster in batch. The manifests folder stores the manifest files generated by Firehose.